why does condarc file not work in Conda when exucute conda install?
The problem is like this：
>conda config --show-sources
==> C:\Users\LT\.condarc <==
channels:
  - defaults
custom_channels:
  conda-forge: http://mirrors.aliyun.com/anaconda/cloud
  msys2: http://mirrors.aliyun.com/anaconda/cloud
  bioconda: http://mirrors.aliyun.com/anaconda/cloud
  menpo: http://mirrors.aliyun.com/anaconda/cloud
  pytorch: http://mirrors.aliyun.com/anaconda/cloud
  simpleitk: http://mirrors.aliyun.com/anaconda/cloud
default_channels:
  - http://mirrors.aliyun.com/anaconda/pkgs/main
  - http://mirrors.aliyun.com/anaconda/pkgs/r
  - http://mirrors.aliyun.com/anaconda/pkgs/msys2
show_channel_urls: True

>conda install pandas
Channels:
 - defaults
 - conda-forge
 - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
 - microsoft
Platform: win-64

when execute the conda install command, it uses another config, what happends？
I also uses conda clean -i to remove cache config before execute  conda install,but it dosen't work.

My guess is that you already have packages from the other repos/channels in your environment.  Does it happen if you use conda create?
